# How to use both Android.App.Fragment and Support V4 library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-support-library, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to use a Support library to add a new L-styled ActionBar to my app. So I changed my activity to an `ActionBarActivity`. Now I have both `getFragmentManager()` and `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

I use `getFragmentManager()` to work with fragments and they are rendered OK.
But there is a problem when I add transaction to backstack (`(mTransaction.addToBackStack("blabla"))`). Backstack remains empty so if I call `mTransaction.commit()` and right after `getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()` latter will return 0 no matter how many transaction I commit. As a result my app will be closed at first "bacK" press without navigation to previous fragment.

*Why I don't use Fragments from Support Library?*
App is targeted to API 15 and newer so I don't care about <11 and there is lot of code to migrate. Also if use Support Library i won't be able to use `objectAnimator` for transition. It isn't disaster, but I just don't want to degrade one part of app to improve another.

So the question - is it possible to fix back stack or i should migrate all fragment-related code to support-v4?

Comment: what's your question ?

Comment: In short - how to fix backstack functionality

Comment: Why don't you just stick with one of the Fragment types? Otherwise you will have to create your own `backstack` and work with `instance of` `if's`

Comment: @PedroOliveira that's what I actually want - use Android.App.Fragment &co. Support Library is used only for new fancy ActionBar.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I was posting too fast before reading your question carefully.
I've looked through the source code of [FragmentActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java) and [Activity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java) and I highly recommend to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` if using ActionBarActivity.
The reason is that the FragmentManager implementation `mFragments` is shadowed in FragmentActivity and is used all over the activity life cycle. If using `getFragmentManager()` the super classes implementation will be accessed. And you will have to rely on FragmentActivity to make the super calls at appropriate times, else the life cycle might get messed up. With `onBackPressed()` you've already discovered a case where FragmentActivity fails to call super.

Another solution would be to migrate to [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html). But you'd loose some of the goodies of ActionBarActivity e.g. widget-tinting and ChildFragmentManager.

I'd just stick with the support implementation.

This is the original answer and doesn't really apply here:

> Committing a fragment transaction, does not immediately add/replace your fragment. Therefore your back stack will still be empty. You can call `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()` if this is really necessary.
>
> Btw: Why would using the support library prevent you from using ObjectAnimator ?

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to get solution for my problem.

Comment: And about ObjectAnimator. ``setCustomAnimations`` of SupportLibrary's FragmentManager won't accept it because it requires old-style animation which is the only available on older APIs.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after few more test I found that actually back stack is filled but it is not handled by activity.
Adding following code solved my problem but i'd like to keep this question open since I still don't know why it isn't handled by `ActionBarACtivity` internally as it is done in `Activity`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();

    }
}
```